# Что такое ReadOnlySequence?

Tags: c#, .net, память, buffer

Что такое `ReadOnlySequence`? Я знаю зачем нужны и как использовать `Span` и `Memory`, но не знаю, зачем нужна эта последовательность. Какие-то `SequencePosition`, `ReadOnlySequenceSegment`. Я смотрел, как их использовать и видел что-то типо такого:

```cs
ReadOnlySequence<byte> bytes = ...;
// ...
foreach (var _byte in bytes)
{
   if (_byte.Span[0] == 0x00)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Вопрос, чем это хуже этого:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes = ...;
// ...
foreach (var _byte in bytes)
{
   if (_byte == 0x00)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Span`/`ReadOnlySpan` и `Memory`/`ReadOnlyMemory` представляют последовательные (непрерывные) блоки памяти и для большинства кейсов этого достаточно (массивы, stackalloc, строки и т.д.), но в некоторых случаях нам нужно работать с разными участками памяти (несколькими объектами `Memory` как одним целым), тогда и нужен `ReadOnlySequence`. Это по факту linked list из `ReadOnlyMemory`. Не `ReadOnly` версии не существует, т.к. исхотя из шаблонов использования, рабработчики .net посчитали, что писать в разные области памяти не логично.

В обычном/реальном коде вы использовать его скорее всего не будет так же часно как `Span`. Чаще всего, вернее единственное место, которое я знаю, где это точно используется, это [Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/), новое API которое работает поверх Streams, вместе с оберткой в виде [SequenceReader](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-sequencereader).

`Pipelines` + `ReadOnlySequence` позволяют упростить код чтения, программисту не нужно волноваться о размере буфера, о том, что было прочитано не полное сообщение, т.е. нужно сохранить текущий буфер и дочитать данные, или наоборот было прочитано слишком много.

Если посмотреть на простой пример:

```
var stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
var reader = PipeReader.Create(stream);

while (true)
{
    // выполняем чтение
    ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();
    ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;

    // тут некая обработка данных
    Process(ref buffer);

    // тут мы говорим сколько мы фактически использовали данные и сколько просмотрели
    // использованные данные будут "уничтожены", а вот те, что просмотрели останутся
    reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

    // завершение чтения, если нет данных
    if (result.IsCompleted)
        break;
}

await reader.CompleteAsync();
```

Код получается довольно простой, но вышеописанные проблемы он решает. Например, у вас при первом, чтении было прочитано 4096 байт, на этом этапе будет создан `ReadOnlySequence` состоящий из одного блока памяти, но дальше по коду `Process` начинает обрабатывать этот данные и понимает, что ему не достаточно, тогда он использует `AnvanceTo` и говорит `reader`-у, что я использовал 0 байт, но простотрел все 4096, на следующем этапе цикла будет прочитан ещё один блок 4096 байт (в отдельный буфер) и `Process` уже может хватить информации. Вот тут то и появляется упрощение/польза `Pipelines` + `ReadOnlySequence`, т.к. руками код стал бы значительно сложнее и медленнее (больше алокаций), в статье про `Pipelines` можно сравнить размер кода.

Comment: Когда я повнимательнее изучил `ReadOnlySequenceSegment`, я понял, что это linked list, но мне не давал покоя конструктор, который принимает массив. Зачем он? Почему не `ReadOnlyMemory`, а массив?